# What is the last char in lexicography order?

Tags: java, char

I'd like to know what is the last char that exists in java?
I have a program which deals with words ordered in lexicography, I just wanna make sure at most that a certain word would be last this is why I wanna know what char should it be?

**edited:** I don't mean the last char from string. 
More simply, I'd like to know what should be the first char in a string that I'd like to be considered as last in lexic order - notice: when I use string.**compareTo** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about simple `char` values, then the answer is `'\uffff'`.  (Java `char` values are really just signed 16-bit integers, and `'\uffff'` or `65535` is the largest integer representable by that type.  The `\u` is Java's Unicode escape syntax.)

However, that ignores the fact that a single Java `char` instance can only represent Unicode codepoints that falls within Unicode plane 0 (the BMP).  The standard currently defines planes 0 through 16.  Code points in the higher planes are represented as pairs of Java `char` values; they are called surrogate pairs.

**You** will need to decide if your application **needs to** deal with surrogate pairs.  (It depends whether you want to support text that uses "esoteric" characters in the higher Unicode planes.)  If it does, then you won't be able to use the standard `String.compareTo` method and the like.  I recommend that you take a look at the [ICU libraries](http://userguide.icu-project.org/).

Comment: edited my question according to the information u provided. hope u can provide more answers :)

Comment: I don't think there is anything more to add.  What did you expect me to add?

Comment: basiclly, i'd like to know what should be the last string when using compareTo method.?

Comment: That is moot.  If you are planning support Unicode codepoints beyond 65535, `compareTo` won't work.  See above.

Comment: @Popokoko The "last string" would have to be infinitely long.

Comment: But if you do use `compareTo`, then the string that compares lexicographically last would consist of an infinite number of `\uffff` codes.  So, the first character of that string will be `0xffff`.  This all follows from the definition of *lexical ordering* in the javadoc for the String.compareTo method.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't represent a valid Unicode character, but the largest value for a `char`, and therefore the "last" character, is 65535.

```
char omega = '\uFFFF';
```

Comment: That's interesting, can u please explain why this is the last char exist?

Answer (score -3):

Did you want the last char from a string? if so:

```
    s.charAt(s.length()-1);
```